# Box on and axis coordinates in a Matlab picture

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to construct a picture in Matlab. I want the box of the plot to be included (`box on` ) and the coordinates of the axis reported up to the limit I set. Consider for example

```
scatter(-0.5, 0.399, 'c','filled');
box on
axis([-0.504 -0.494 0.397 0.408 ])
legend('A')
xlabel('\gamma_0')
ylabel('\delta_0')
title('N=3')
```

Now, you can see that on the vertical axis the last tick at the top is not numerated. I don't understand why. Could you help to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is only a visualization issue. If you want to make sure your limits are shown you may force the ticks value:

```
scatter(-0.5, 0.399, 'c','filled');
box on
axis([-0.504 -0.494 0.397 0.408 ])

xticks(linspace(-0.504, -0.494, 11)); % Set the ticks vector as a vector of 11 elements from -0.504 to -0.494
yticks(linspace(0.397, 0.408, 11));

legend('A')
xlabel('\gamma_0')
ylabel('\delta_0')
title('N=3')
```

[image: Image in my matlab]

In your comment you specified you want only three digits format. In format string that is `'%1.3f'`. You can force also the formatting of your ticks:

```
scatter(-0.5, 0.399, 'c','filled');
box on
axis([-0.504 -0.494 0.397 0.408 ])

xtickformat('%1.3f');
ytickformat('%1.3f');
xticks(linspace(-0.504, -0.494, 11)); 
yticks(linspace(0.397, 0.408, 11));

legend('A')
xlabel('\gamma_0')
ylabel('\delta_0')
title('N=3')
```

this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like that now Matlab is using ticks with 4 digits after the comma

Comment: As the format produced by my code: for the y-axis 0.397, 0.398,..., 0.408; for the x-axis -0.504, -0.503, ..., -0.494

Comment: Check the last part of the answer

Comment: I would recommend against rounding the tick mark labels, and instead round the tick mark locations. Because along the y axis you now have tick labels that do not exactly match the location of the tick marks. Better would be to use the array `0.396:0.002:0.408` as tick marks.

Comment: For sure you have to consider which is the number of significant digits for your problem. I think the OP chose 3.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening looks to be a floating-point rounding issue. Octave curiously does exactly the same thing.

```
>> axis([-0.504 -0.494 0.397 0.408 ])
>> t=get(gca,'ytick')
t =
   0.39600   0.39800   0.40000   0.40200   0.40400   0.40600   0.40800

>> l=get(gca,'ylim')
l =
   0.39700   0.40800

>> t(end)-l(end)
ans =
   5.5511e-17
```

So there is a tick mark at 0.408, but the location of the tick mark is still just above the axis limit, so it is not shown.

You can explicitly set the tick locations, as [Matteo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52992059/7328782) suggests, or explicitly set the axis limits:

```
ylim([0.397,t(end)])
```

Note that the trick here is to use the exact location of the tick mark, `t(end)`, rather than the constant `0.408`, which is a different value.

Comment: Thanks: I don't understand how you construct `t`. If I type `t=get(gca,'ytick')` I get a vector from `0` to `1`.

Comment: If I run `scatter(-0.5, 0.399, 'c','filled');
box on
ylim([0.397, 0.408])
legend('A')
xlabel('\gamma_0')
ylabel('\delta_0')
title('N=3')` the problem is not solved.

Comment: Type these commands *after* you type the code in your question. `gca` is the current axis. If you click on different axes, those axes will become `gca`. So make sure the figure you create in your question is the last one that was active.

Comment: And, yes, that was the point. `0.408` is not the location of the tick mark. The tick mark and the axis limit are rounded in different directions, meaning that the tick mark ends up just outside the axis limit.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the ticks manually using the function *set*

```
scatter(-0.5, 0.399, 'c','filled');
box on
axis([-0.504 -0.494 0.397 0.408 ])
legend('A')
xlabel('\gamma_0')
ylabel('\delta_0')
title('N=3')
yTickDiff = diff(get(gca,'YTick'));
set(gca,'YTick',[0.397:yTickDiff(1):0.408])
```